# MacBook Air disbalanced sound in anything but macOS

Tags: linux, windows, mac, audio, uefi

Currently have a MacBookAir7,2 with the standard config (1.8Ghz, 8Gb LPDDR3, 128Gb PCIe SSD) and I of course installed Ubuntu on it.

Upon booting Ubuntu I immediately noticed that the speakers sounded very odd. After some testing, I found that the left speaker produced plenty of low frequencies and was generally balanced across the board, and the right speaker was skewed to the upper frequencies, generally sounding "tinny." This occurred in all non-Apple OS's, including Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, but should apply to any Linux distribution with the standard snd_intel_hda drivers.

The audio chip is a CS4208 by Cirrus Logic, however under native EFI boot (which I used, and macOS also uses) the sound interface is exposed as the Intel HDA controller (under legacy boot, all Macs show the Cirrus Logic as its own device, and this is done by the EFI, which also disables integrated graphics on MacBook Pro's with dual GPU's under legacy boot, and for newer macs, native EFI boot.) I had a copy of Windows and upon installing it, it also showed the same problem (efi boot with bootmgfw.efi.) So, being a power user at heart, got to work on how macOS didn't have this issue.

First, some background. Before 2011, when all macs used the BIOS-CSM to boot windows (officially, windows 8.1 and earlier could not boot natively due to Apple's out-of-spec EFI, not UEFI implementation,) *and* the apple-set-os protocol didn't exist (tested by me as well with a 2010 mac,) this was solved by using an EFI booter to load an operating system, which exposed all hardware natively, without an interposing layer. When Windows 10 was released, bootmgfw.efi surprisingly worked on EFI 1.1 machines (tested by me, on that 2010 MacBook,) as previously bootmgfw.efi would freeze when trying to load windows. This drastically improved battery life as well.

After 2010, I concluded that Apple must have upgraded the EFI implementation on their computers to UEFI 2.0 compliant, which meant that Windows was now bootable (at the time, of course.) They needed a way to differentiate between macOS and other operating systems, as now they endorsed installing Windows via UEFI (transparently, as most users were using BootCamp Assistant.app, which manages that.) I could tell as it is obvious that when booting using the CSM, the blinking cursor will be shown on-screen, and boot graphics are stretched (if using a non-vesa resolution, the closest available resolution or 1024x768 are used instead, which creates a discernible effect)

To differentiate between the two, they added the apple-set-os protocol in the EFI. Setting this to Mac OS X 10.* would expose all hardware natively, and if left unset, the EFI applies a "compatibility layer" which disabled the integrated GPU if present with a discrete GPU, and changed the way the sound interface was exposed. A namesake utility was developed, and is available here: https://github.com/0xbb/apple_set_os.efi which would manually set this value, which would allow the integrated graphics to show (this was the original goal) and would allow a thunderbolt gpu to use Optimus or the AMD equivalent to have the internal display driven by the integrated Intel GPU, which was desired for gaming as this would allow the external graphics write to the Intel framebuffer (this is how *real* optimus works, but in this case it can be used with external graphics.)

I got this utility, added it to refind, and got on my way. When invoked, and a non-apple OS run, it appears that it disables some compatibility interface for the internal trackpad and keyboard, which are SPI internally and incompatible with anything but macOS (The relevant drivers are AppleHSSPIHIDDriver.kext and AppleHSSPISupport.kext.) This occurred in both Windows and Ubuntu.

In Windows, I used Remote Desktop to control the mac on Windows (everything except the keyboard input and trackpad, even though the keyboard backlights worked) and the sound was perfect. It appears that Apple unbelievably intentionally crippled sound for non-macOS operating systems. Or it appears to be. I checked and double checked myself, and each time the difference was noticeable. With apple_set_os set, the keyboard and trackpad were set to SPI (Or at least, not made visible easily in comparison) and the internal speakers sounded perfectly equal. Without apple_set_os set, the internal keyboard and trackpad worked with either Windows' generic HID Drivers, or the Apple-supplied enhanced ones, and the sound was disbalanced in the same way each time.

Now, with Ubuntu. I tried both. With apple_set_os set, the keyboard and trackpad again were undetected and non-functional. However, the speakers sounded disbalanced again. I tried without apple_set_os set, and the internal input devices worked, and the sound stayed the same. However, one difference was that with apple_set_os set, artifacts displayed on screen during boot were black, while without it set, the artifacts were in the same location but garbled with RGB colors.

I am completely unsure of what the issue is. However, as shown by the speakers sounding normal in Windows after the apple_set_os hack, and not sounding normal in Ubuntu with the same hack, leaves me wondering. I realize that the length of this question and the fact that nobody can truly be certain of what is happening will probably bar this from even receiving a concrete answer, but I wanted to point it out nonetheless and see if anything surfaces.